# Ensuring Jira Plugins do not Cause Issues with Future Jira Upgrades

Tags: jira

When installing free/paid for jira plugins, is there a badge or certificate that we should look for in the plugin to ensure that it does not cause issues with the jira instance when it's upgraded? I.e. that it's backwards compatible?

We have a shared jira instance at our workplace and when we ask for new plugin installation, there is some concern from jira admins that the plugin may prohibit future upgrades on the instance if the plugin is broken by the upgrade in jira.

Eg the following scenario:

1. plugin is installed on jira instance
2. lots of people start using the plugin
3. jira admin attempts to upgrade the jira instance but finds it breaks the plugin
4. jira admin can't upgrade jira because of this one broken plugin

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no badge or certificate that ensures them to keep it up to date. 
But there are other things you can look at as an indicator if it is well maintained.

First things I would look at is the version history, amount of downloads on the plugin and if the company providing the plugin has multiple plugins.

However none of these are certainties.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer (waiting for my reputation to increase before i can upvote)